# jQuery iterate through table column

Tags: php, jquery

I'd like to iterate through a tables columns. Given I have a cell Id, I then want to get the values of the rest of the cells in that column.

The reason for this is, I want to add some validation so that 3 cells in a column, can't all contain the same class.

I'm open to ideas using both jQuery or PHP.

If you require more information, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery to get an item's column:

```
var column = $('#myID').index();
```

To parse through the table by the nth column:

```
var columnNth = $('#myID').index() + 1;
var items = [];


$('#tblID tbody tr td:nth-child('+columnNth +')').each( function(){
   //add item to array
   items.push( $(this).attr('class'); );       
});
```