# jQuery iterate table column and rows to build lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am trying to build a function that will alleviate some manual aspect to a project.  The client has provided me with a list in Excel which I have converted to a table (thanks to Notepad++ and some nifty jQuery script).

My goal is to make ***individual lists*** of all the columns each comprised of the column header, and the **"X"** cells, but the **"X"** cells will have text in them that matches the first `<td>` of each row.

I took a try at it and failed so I'm hoping someone can see what I was aiming for and point out my flaws.

The route I was taking was to get everything into a neatly oriented array that I would then iterate through to create `<div><ul><li>Column Header</li><li>text from first Row (X replaced)</li> etc...</ul></div>`

I suspect that my row iteration and column iteration is backwards but any help would be appreciated.

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34212184/5076162) has the gist of what I need but is not as comprehensive as I would like.

```js
$('td').each(function() {
    var currentHTML = $(this).html().toString();
    if (currentHTML === "&nbsp;") {
        $(this).text("").addClass('nonX');
    }
});

var columnIteration = $('tr:eq(0)').find('td').length;
console.log(columnIteration);
var corespondingTD = [];
for (i = 1, z = columnIteration; i < z; i++) {
 $('tr').each(function() {
  var rowIterated = [];
  var columnHeader = $('tr:eq(0)').find($('td').eq(i)).text();
  var xTD = $(this).find($('td').eq(i)).not($('td.nonX'));
  rowIterated.push(columnHeader);
  rowIterated.push(xTD);
  corespondingTD.push(rowIterated);
 });
}
```

```css
table {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>WILLOW ADD-ON
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$6.99</td>
            <td>TV ASIA<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$9.99</td>
            <td>ZEE TV &amp; STAR INDIA PLUS 2-Pack<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>$14.99</td>
            <td>SET ASIA &amp; STAR INDIA PLUS 2-Pack<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>$14.99</td>
            <td>Hindi 4-Pack
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$24.99</td>
            <td>Hindi 4-Pack
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$24.99</td>
            <td>Hindi 4-Pack
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$24.99</td>
            <td>Desi 4-Pack<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$29.99</td>
            <td>Hindi 8-Pack
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$34.99</td>
            <td>Desi Mega Pack: SET, TV Asia, Zee, Star Plus, Life OK, ABP News, Star Gold
                <br> $42.99
            </td>
            <td>Hindi 12-Pack
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$44.99</td>
            <td>Tamil 2-Pack
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$14.99</td>
            <td>Punjabi 2-Pack
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$14.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABP NEWS</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AAPKA COLORS</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EROS NOW: VIDEO ON DEMAND <font class="font5">($9.99/mo. Add-On)</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LIFE OK</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NDTV 24x7</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>NDTV GOOD TIMES
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SAB</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SONY MIX</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>STAR INDIA PLUS
                <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>STAR INDIA GOLD
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SET ASIA</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TV ASIA</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ZEE BOLLYWOOD</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ZEE TV</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>WILLOW</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>VIJAY</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SUN TV</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JUS PUNJABI</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TV84</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <!--EndFragment-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example with a simpler table that creates an object that contains properties corresponding to the column headers identified by an **x** with a value of an array of the corresponding row headers. I left some logging lines in there so you can see what is happening with the code as it figures out row and column header values for each **x** :

```js
var lists = {};

buildLists();

console.log(JSON.stringify(lists, null, 2));

function buildLists() {
  $('#data tbody tr td').each(function() {
    var columnIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    if ($(this).html() == 'x') {
      var columnHeader = getTableCellValue('data', 0, columnIndex);
      var rowHeader = getTableCellValue('data', rowIndex, 0);

      //console.log('hit at ' + rowIndex + ' ' + columnIndex);
      //console.log(getTableCellValue('data', rowIndex, columnIndex));
      //console.log(columnHeader + ' : ' + rowHeader);

      if (!lists[columnHeader]) {
        lists[columnHeader] = [];
      }
      lists[columnHeader].push(rowHeader);

    }; 
  });
};

function getTableCellValue(tableId, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
  var cell = $('#' + tableId + ' tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(columnIndex)
  return cell.text();
}
```

```css
table {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table id="data">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody> 
  </table>
</body>
```

With your table (which I gave an `id="data"`), it still works but I think you need to fiddle with the solution a little bit to get your object property names a bit less verbose:

```js
var lists = {};

buildLists();

console.log(JSON.stringify(lists, null, 2));

function buildLists() {
  $('#data tbody tr td').each(function() {
    var columnIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    if ($(this).html() == 'x') {
      var columnHeader = getTableCellValue('data', 0, columnIndex);
      var rowHeader = getTableCellValue('data', rowIndex, 0);

      //console.log('hit at ' + rowIndex + ' ' + columnIndex);
      //console.log(getTableCellValue('data', rowIndex, columnIndex));
      //console.log(columnHeader + ' : ' + rowHeader);

      if (!lists[columnHeader]) {
        lists[columnHeader] = [];
      }
      lists[columnHeader].push(rowHeader);

    }; 
  });
};

function getTableCellValue(tableId, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
  var cell = $('#' + tableId + ' tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(columnIndex)
  return cell.text();
}
```

```css
table {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table id="data">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>WILLOW ADD-ON
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$6.99</td>
              <td>TV ASIA<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$9.99</td>
              <td>ZEE TV &amp; STAR INDIA PLUS 2-Pack<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </span>$14.99</td>
              <td>SET ASIA &amp; STAR INDIA PLUS 2-Pack<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </span>$14.99</td>
              <td>Hindi 4-Pack
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$24.99</td>
              <td>Hindi 4-Pack
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$24.99</td>
              <td>Hindi 4-Pack
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$24.99</td>
              <td>Desi 4-Pack<span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$29.99</td>
              <td>Hindi 8-Pack
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$34.99</td>
              <td>Desi Mega Pack: SET, TV Asia, Zee, Star Plus, Life OK, ABP News, Star Gold
                  <br> $42.99
              </td>
              <td>Hindi 12-Pack
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$44.99</td>
              <td>Tamil 2-Pack
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$14.99</td>
              <td>Punjabi 2-Pack
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>$14.99</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>ABP NEWS</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>AAPKA COLORS</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>EROS NOW: VIDEO ON DEMAND <font class="font5">($9.99/mo. Add-On)</font></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>LIFE OK</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>NDTV 24x7</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>NDTV GOOD TIMES
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>SAB</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>SONY MIX</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>STAR INDIA PLUS
                  <span style="mso-spacerun:yes">&nbsp;</span></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>STAR INDIA GOLD
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>SET ASIA</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>TV ASIA</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>ZEE BOLLYWOOD</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>ZEE TV</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>WILLOW</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>VIJAY</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>SUN TV</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>JUS PUNJABI</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>TV84</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>x</td>
          </tr>
          <!--EndFragment-->
      </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: that you very much for this.  It allowed me to do exactly what I needed.  You were right about the column headers being too wordy.  How to I dynamically iterate through a JSON object that is not uniformly constructed?